# How can I predict the future data by past data?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, regression, data-science, predictive

If I have past data of employees for several years and want to predict the future data depending on the their behavior of taking their vacations, which algorithm or model is best for that? Any recommnedations or suggestions?

For example:
I took 10 days off in June 2019 and 15 days off in December 2019 BUT I took 15 days off in June 2018 and 15 days off in December 2018, so what is the prediction of June and December of 2020? Obviously this is not enough to predict that but it's jsut for an idea to udnerstand the problem.

Any ideas about it?

Answer (score 3):

Try with these tutorials [RNN](https://towardsdatascience.com/time-series-forecasting-with-rnns-ff22683bbbb0) or [LSTM](https://towardsdatascience.com/lstm-for-time-series-prediction-de8aeb26f2ca) algorithms

Comment: Time Series Forecasting is not a good solution since I need the monthly prediction and number of holidays the employee is going to take in the next year.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout `Time Series`

Few helpful links:

- [End to end time series project](https://towardsdatascience.com/an-end-to-end-project-on-time-series-analysis-and-forecasting-with-python-4835e6bf050b)
- [Seven day mini course](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-get-started-with-deep-learning-for-time-series-forecasting-7-day-mini-course/)

Comment: Time Series Forecasting is not a good solution since I need the monthly prediction and number of holidays the employee is going to take in the next year.